# Client X and ClientY for touch Screen

Tags: javascript

I do have a game which follows the client X and Client Y.
But on phone, this won't work. I added `joystick.js` and I used e.deltaX and Y, but it didn't work the joystick should make the client follows DeltaX and DeltaY.

Here are the codes I will add:

```
document.getElementById("overlays2").onmousemove = function(e) {
  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY;
  paint();
};
```

I used [this GitHUB link](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/virtualjoystick.js).

Comment: Virtualjoystick seems to handle touch events, check how it is done. Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Answer (score 2):

You can use on tap command for mobile.
It will work fine on only mobiles or touch device